# Conditional expectation of a bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have a bounded random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$
  and some other random variable $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$
 . Then the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]$
  is again a bounded random variable, measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
 .

In particular, we can then find a Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
  such that $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]=f(Y)$
 .

My question is this: Obviously $f\circ Y$
  is bounded, but can I be sure that $f$
  is also bounded?

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: I guess you could set $f$ to be zero outside of $Y(\Omega)$?

Comment: @angryavian: That's a good point. We know $f$ must be bounded on the range of $Y$, so if that's really all we care about, then why not just set it equal to $0$ outside. But I suppose we need $Y(\Omega)$ to measurable to do this?

Comment: $f$ is $Y_*P$-almost surely bounded. That is, if we push forward the measure $P$ with $Y$, and if we consider $f$ as a random variable here, then $f$ is bounded with probability 1. This should suffice for any practical purposes?